# How to fetch json data without bugs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I want to fetch in react using useEffect hook but there is an issue 
this is my code from a landing-page.jsx file :

```
import "./landing-page.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Landing_page() {
const [data, set_data] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("./db.json")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((d) => console.log(d));
}, []);
```

and this is my db.json file :

```
{
"projects": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
        "level_name": "newbie",
        "level_number": "1",
        "description": "Fugiat quibusdam tempore explicabo earum perferendis, pariatur dolores. Vitae perspiciatis officia nobis?",
        "preview_link": "https://google.com",
        "github_link": "https://google.com"
    }
]
```

}
I want to get this JSON file inside landing-page.json file with useEffect and fetch but it doesn't work and shows this error in the console:
[image]

** and remind you both these files are in the same folder

Comment: Why are you trying to use fetch on a json file? Can you not just import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the db.json file inside the public folder because during runtime the "/" path is going to be the public folder and not the src folder. Alternatively you can import the db.json file if it's in your src folder. import db from './db.json'.

As others have stated. In a real DB fetch situation, you're going to specify the full path to the resource such as "URL:PORT/endPointName"

Comment: Working sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-bogdan-eyzcbu?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getProjects =async ()=>{
  const res = await axios.get("./db.json");
  set_data(res.projects)
  getProjects()
}
   
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

by using `JSON-server` then you will need to specify the full URL from your `localhost`. not the path to the file. the key of your JSON which is `projects` is your `API` that you're going to call. `http://localhost:3000` is your localhost that is needed to make your request.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/projects")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((d) => console.log(d));
}, []);
```